# Vue jsx event handlers

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, jsx, dom-events, vue-events

Is there any docs section which clarifies why I should use camel case for click handler, but kebab for input (and everything else)? But not for click, for click only `onClick` works.

Actually I noticed that for common input both options work fine either `on-input` or `onInput`.

```
const MyJSXInput = {
  props: {
    value: {
      type: Boolean,
      required: true
    },
    clickHandler: {
      type: Function,
      required: true
    },
    inputHandler: {
      type: Function,
      required: true
    },
  },
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
  render(createElement) {
    const { value, clickHandler, inputHandler } = this.$props
    return (
      <input onClick={clickHandler} on-input={inputHandler} type="checkbox" value={value} />
    )
  }
}
```

Don't know if it matters, but I use this component as render function prop for another component. Like this (all simplified):

```
    renderProp: () => (
      <MyJSXInput 
        value={someValue}
        click-handler={this.someHandlerClick}
        input-handler={this.someHandlerInput}
      />
    )
```

And this final component has things like that:

```
  render(h) {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.$props.renderProp(this)}
      </div>
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found piece of info here:

https://github.com/vuejs/babel-plugin-transform-vue-jsx#difference-from-react-jsx

However I still have no idea why kebab case works for input event.

Answer (score 1):

In React jsx, element event binding use camel case: `onClick` or `onMouseDown`.

But in [html Specification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers), event binding is full lower case: `onclick` or `onmousedown`.

So React babel plugin transfrom camel case to lower case.

In Vue, [vue jsx plugin](https://github.com/vuejs/jsx) which transform jsx to vue render funciton, do noting about lower case.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rOCn.png)